# Is there a better way to check if a list of strings contains a string that begins with a string from another list?

Tags: python, string

Yes, the question was confusing.
The problem is:
I have a list of strings (let's call it list1) ["abc","acd","df"] and another list of prefixes of variable length (list2) ["ha","ab","ad",..]. I want to count the number of elements of list1 which contain an element of list2 at the beginning. I did something using python, but I feel that's slow. I haven't done a benchmark test as the code for speed.

I've solved it using two for loops but I feel that's too inefficient. My current solution in Python:

```py
def match(string,prefixes):
  for i in prefixes:
    if match.beginswith(i):
      return 1
  return 0

def countmatches(list,prefixes):
  totalmat=0 
  for elem in list:
    totalmat+=match(elem,prefixes)
  return totalmat
```

Any tips or tricks I can use to make this faster? My current method is O(nk) where n is number of elements and k is number of prefixes.
Edit:

```py
The specific code as of this example was:
def match(string, prefixes):
    for i in prefixes:
        if string.startswith(i):
            return 1
    return 0
def countmatches(list, prefixes):
    matches=[e for e in list if match(e)==1]
    return len(matches)
```

I later updated the code so it uses a list comprehension over a tuple:

Minimal working example:

```py
import time
def countmatches(list,prefixtuple):
    matches= [e for e in list if e.startswith(prefixtuple)]
    return len(matches)
Prefixes=tuple(["X0","Y7","z34","W3","X23"])# (It's constant size. The actual prefix list has around 15 elements)
list=["X23789","V78930","H789078","W23445"]# (The list is of variable size.)
init=time.time()*1000.0
match=countmatches(list,Prefixes)
deltat=time.time()*1000.0-init
print(f"Time: {deltat}")
if(match>0):
  print(list)
```

counting time using time.time(), I got around 0.1 seconds to process 100000 lists, can't really send that code to stackoverflow as it's proprietary.

Every element in the list should only match a single prefix as the prefixes are filtered.

Comment: Could you share a minimal working example? How do you call the functions? What do you mean with slow?

Comment: Yeah, the function was supposed to be string.beginswith(i). That should work.

Comment: *"Every element in the list should only match a single prefix as the prefixes are filtered."* - So your original example isn't realistic in that regard?

Comment: You should not use a variable name list in python!

Comment: Now you introduce lower and upper case matches, how should this be counted, e.g. z is not matching Z ? If you read 100000 elements, I assume the time is lost from reading the input too. Do you read from a file? Do you measure CPU or Wall time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex can very quickly check whether a word matches a list of prefixes, by using an alternation; e.g. `re.match("a|ab|ad", word)`. However, it can be even faster, in several ways:

- Compiling the regex in advance, if it will be used multiple times
- Removing alternations with the same prefix
- Removing prefixes whose prefix is itself in a list (e.g. all words that start with `ad` will also start with `a`, so testing for `ad` is redundant)

`re.compile` can help with the first point, and using the package `trieregex` can help with the second point. For example, the following snippet will use the regex `'^a[bd]?'`, and produce `2`:

```
import re
from trieregex import TrieRegEx

prefixes = ["a", "ab", "ad"]
words = ["abc", "acd", "df"]

tregex = TrieRegEx(*prefixes)
regex = re.compile(tregex.regex())

match_count = sum(1 for word in words if regex.match(word))
print(match_count)
```

Note that this is slower than the brute force approach when the lists are small, due to extra work needed to construct the prefix trie and generate the regex; but on large lists, it will provide significant speedups.

The third optimisation can be done by replacing

```
tregex = TrieRegEx(*prefixes)
regex = re.compile(tregex.regex())
```

with

```
tregex = TrieRegEx()
regex = None
for prefix in sorted(prefixes):
    if regex and regex.match(prefix):
        continue
    tregex.add(prefix)
    regex = re.compile(tregex.regex())
```

which checks for each prefix if it is already handled by the current regex before adding it. For example, if the list of prefixes is

```
["a", "ab", "ad", "ba", "bang", "bet"]
```

then `"ab"`, `"ad"` and `"bang"` are skipped (since they are handled by `"a"` and `"ba"`), and the resulting regex is a very sleek `(?:b(?:et|a)|a)`.

Comment: He will count the hits in list1, therefore I think it should be 3 (a is 2x in list1 +  ab is 1x) or I am wrong?

Comment: @Hermann12 No, "number of elements of list1 which contain an element of list2 at the beginning" is two.

Comment: An element or more will be counted as one. Than it’s fine. The question is not unambiguous , but this is our Interpretation.

Comment: That preprocessing for the third optimization might be slow, right? Due to repeatedly building the regex. Depends on the daya. I wish the OP had provided a benchmark...

Comment: @KellyBundy Two points: a) the regex is only rebuilt if a non-redundant prefix is encountered; so it depends on how many redundant prefixes there are, relative to the non-redundant ones; b) even if preprocessing takes a long time it could still ultimately save time if the list of the words to check is very long. As you said, it depends on the data. It may be better to omit the third optimisation. In fact, for the provided sample data, the naive brute-force `sum(1 for word in words if any(prefix for prefix in prefixes if word.startswith(prefix)))` is likely the fastest.

Comment: I think `sum(1 for word in words if word.startswith(prefixes))` is a faster naive brute-force (just needs a one-time conversion to a *tuple* of prefixes).

Comment: @KellyBundy Oh, indeed. I was not aware `str.startswith` accepts a tuple.

Comment: Thanks for this. Regex preprocessing did the trick for me because I was processing millions of lists.

Comment: Checking again. The speeds of a tuple and regex were pretty similar.  Although regex has  a slight edge (about 0.05 seconds per 100000 lists) over tuples, They seem to have pretty similar times at total.

Comment: It makes sense, as both of those are processing all prefixes in C, leaving you with only a single loop in Python (as opposed to two nested loops in Python).

Comment: that looks like a handy library

Comment: Ugh, why did I write it like that... The brute-force one should have been `sum(1 for word in words if any(word.startswith(prefix) for prefix in prefixes))`... though Kelly Bundy's `sum(1 for word in words if word.startswith(prefixes_tuple))` is better, of course.